# Command to print few consecutive lines from middle of a file

Tags: text-processing, command, head

For a file containing 20 lines, lines 6-10 can be printed using following command:

```
head -10 filename | tail -5
```

Can this exactly same thing be done without using 'head' and 'tail' commands ??

Please comment the link if similar question already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` would work well here

```
seq 20 | sed '6,10!d'
```

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

You could use this as well: `sed -n '6,10p'`

Or awk, `awk '6 <= NR && NR <= 10'`

Comment: `sed '6,$!d;20q'` to avoid reading the whole input.